# Loading Grunt task attributes from external file

Tags: gruntjs

I am quite new to grunt, literally only a few hours. I am setting up grunt to cache-bust my website using grunt-cache-breaker. Now I have got it to work when I manually type in every file source example:

grunt.initConfig({

```
    cachebreaker: {
        dev: {
            options: {
                match: ['.js', '.css', 'min.css'],
                src: {
                    path: 'TEST/Apps/**/*'
                }
            },
            files: {
                src: ['TEST/Apps/AppTemplate/v1.0.0/index.html',
                      'TEST/Apps/Case_Attributes/v1.0.0/index.html',
                      'TEST/Apps/Case_CorrespondenceReferences/v1.0.0/index.html',
                ',    
                ]
            }
        },
    },
```

});

however what I really want to do is to be able to problematically build the list of files.src from a pre-generated text file like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({

    cachebreaker: {
        dev: {
            options: {
                match: ['.js', '.css', 'min.css'],
                src: {
                    path: 'TEST/Apps/**/*'
                }
            },
            files: {
                src: function (){
                    return grunt.file.read('config.txt')
                }

            }
        },
    },
```

});

or something to this affect. Is this possible? Or am I completely off the mark?

Answer (score 1):

After a few more hours of playing I came up with this solution:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({

   config: grunt.file.readJSON('config.json'),  

   cachebreaker: {
        dev: {
            options: {
                match: ['.js', '.css', 'min.css'],
                src: {
                    path: 'TEST/Apps/**/*'
                }
            },
            files: {
                src: ['<%= config %>'], 
            }
        },
    },
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-cache-breaker');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['cachebreaker']);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

A different and very versatile way to do that is to generate the task parameters in runtime.
Say you load the list of filenames into array `list`. After having called `grunt.initConfig()` you can do this:

```
grunt.config.merge({
    cachebreaker: {
        dev: {
            files: { src: list }
        }
    }
}),
```

That is, update the config object with these other properties you want.